# Failed to load the PDF file message

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am using the react-pdf library in my react vite application to display the pdf which is a `azure blob storage url` .
My requirement is to render the pdf to the user, but instead I am getting a message displayed in the container [`Failed to load PDF document`].

I am providing the `PDFViewer`component and its implementaion.
Please suggest me the slution for it.
`PDFViewer Component :`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import styles from './pdfpreview.module.css';


pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js',
    import.meta.url,
).toString();
// pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const PDFPreview = ({ pdfUrl }) => {
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
        setNumPages(numPages);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Document file={pdfUrl} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} onLoadError={(error) => console.error('PDF Load Error:', error)}>
                <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>
            <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PDFPreview;
```

`Implementaion :`

```
<PDFPreview pdfUrl={questionDetails.data.IntroMediaURL}/>
```